# Arrays Windows Forms Index was outside the bounds

Tags: c#, arrays, forms

there are a couple of these questions asked, but mine primarily involves Windows Forms, which there are few, although if there is an answer, a relatively well explained one without complicated jargon please let me know so I can learn from it.

Cutting to the chase: I want to read some data from a txt file into an array and then display it into some radio buttons. But for here I have simplified it and put them into a messagebox.

```
private void Game1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        const int iGAME = 4;
        string[] sQuestions = new string[iGAME];
        int iNum;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("questions.txt"))
        {
            for (iNum = 0; iNum < iGAME; iNum++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(sQuestions[iGAME]);
            }
        }
```

The problem here is that the system tells me that the index exceeds the bounds. Now I have checked the txt file and there is definitely 4 pieces of information to apply to an array.

Comment: For starters, you aren't actually reading anything out of the file, so whats in it is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Okay, I don't understand how that merits voting my question down though?

Comment: You made a typo, should be iNum not iGame. And your info in the file is totally irrelevant for the snippet posted.

Comment: Probably because that's something you could have seen in a few seconds if you just took the time to set a breakpoint and start the debug mode.

Comment: Not my vote, but yeah, this question doesn't show a lot of debugging effort.

Comment: Funnily enough, I have been using breakpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix my code, to those that are doing a similar sort of thing to me here is my fix, hope it helps you:

```
  int i;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("questions.txt"))
        {
            for (i = 0; i < Questions.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Questions[i] = Convert.ToString(sr.ReadLine()));`
```

What I did here is state the loop variable i, using StreamReader to read the TXT file (don't forget to add using System.IO; at the top of the page. I then created a for loop so that it saves time by assigning each array with data. I then decided to show the results in a messagebox for simplicity by stating the Questions with the array counter [i] and then converted it to a string so it could be read in the box as before hand it was just blank.

Hopefully that little friendly walkthrough helps you solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong index for the array. You're passing `iGAME` (a constant set to `4`) when you should be using `iNum` (a variable between `0-3`). Given that the upper-bound for the index is 3, the `4` will cause the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Also, tip: C# is not C, so you don't need to use separate constants to denote the length of an array, also convention in C-style languages is to use just `i` as an index variable, and it avoids confusion between `iGAME` and `iNum` which has befallen you. Finally, avoid including the type-name in a variable's name, you don't need it anymore, this isn't the 1980s with Hungarian notation. You can rewrite your code to be more maintainable as:

```
String[] questions = new String[ 4 ];
for(int i=0; i<questions.Length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Or just use this:

```
String[] questions = File.ReadAllLines( fileName );
foreach(String question in questions) MessageBox.Show( question );
```

Comment: Funny story, my university course specifies that I use variable definers like 'iNum' or 'sString' as a guide, I forget that professionals do not use the guides, gimme a break

Comment: @AllahuAkbar Correct and proper "Hungarian Notation" (where a variable's name contains information about its purpose) is a good idea and makes sense, however a bastardization of the notation where the **type** of the variable is included in the name became popular decades ago when people edited source using simple text-editors or untyped interpreted languages (like Javascript and VBScript). Today it's largely considered a bad practice, particularly in statically-typed compiled languages like C#. Unfortunately it still permeates things like the Win32 API and COM (e.g. `pSzFoo` and `pIUnknown`).

Comment: I see what you mean now, that makes sense

Comment: @AllahuAkbar Read the WP article for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Answer (score 0):

I dont get what you want but first

`MessageBox.Show(sQuestions[iGAME])` is wrong

change it to

```
MessageBox.Show(sQuestions[iNum ]);
```